# For In loop over class prototypes in typescript behaves differently in es2015

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, prototype

When I compile typescript to es5 this code works just fine for me.

```
export class MyClass {
    public static n: MyClass = <MyClass>{};

    constructor() {
        for (let name in MyClass.prototype) {
            if (MyClass.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                MyClass.n[this[name]] = `${this.constructor.name}.${name}`;
            }
        }
    }

    SomeFunction() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

But if I try to compile to a version newer (es2015, es2016, es2017) This code skips over the for loop as if `DataActions.prototype` is empty. I'm having a hard time finding what changed that breaks this code. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: can you check the compiled js output? You might find the answer there. Also you might have found a bug?

Comment: Nothing really stands out @BalázsÉdes from being compiled. Going to es5 it is converted to a function whereas in es2015 it does use the new js classes.

Comment: It seems that prototype is different in between these two versions. `MyClass.prototype` is es2015 is empty whereas es5 has `SomeFunction`

Comment: Do you transpile the es6 output further, or leave it as it is? As far as I know es6 should still use the same prototypal methods/inheritance but I might be wrong...

Comment: So i'm using tsc to compile a test script `tsc .\test.ts --target es6` or es5. es6 output is basically identical to the typescript except `public static n` line is moved outside of the class. But --target es5 compiles further to a function.

Comment: I understand. I was thinking you are further compiling the output of the ts file, it's a common practice to compile like this: ts -> es6 -> babel -> es5.

Comment: ES6 class methods are non-enumerable, and Typescript does not implement this behavior when compiling to ES5.